# allow file attributes to be read without allowing content to be read

Tags: windows, permissions, network-share, file-permissions

I have a shared folder with with files separated into folders by department (e.g. accounting, IT, etc.) and have permissions set up so people who need to can access those folders.

Is there a way to allow a user (i.e. the IIS APPPOOL user for our intranet site) access to the names of the files and the date they were modified without being able to read the contents?

Our intranet site uses Windows Authentication with impersonate=1 to authenticate the user. I am able to get the information I need if I give the IIS APPPOOL user "List file contents" and "Read" permissions but this allows the user to read the contents. I am looking for a way to just allow a user to read the file attributes(e.g. Created, Modified, Accessed dates, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the 'user' "List Folder Contents" on the folder?

Comment: I tried just "List Folder Contents" before and it said access denied. Now it seems to be working. Thanks